# How to implement custom ViewGroup in RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am using a [CarouselView](https://github.com/sayyam/carouselview) library to show images in a RecyclerView. 
I have created a custom view which uses  this [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) library, to make the images zoomable.

I need to implement a custom ViewGoup class which is explained [here](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView#issues-with-viewgroups). I don't know where to change my RecyclerView Adapter, to use my `CustomViewGroup` instead of the default `ViewGroup`.

My `ViewGroup` class looks like shown

```
class MyViewGroup(context: Context) : ViewGroup(context) {
override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, l: Int, t: Int, r: Int, b: Int) {}

override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    try {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev)
    } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return false
    }

  }
}
```

And this is my recyclerview adapter

```
class MyAdapter(
var dataset: MutableList<Upload> = mutableListOf(),
var context: Context?
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

class ViewHolder(val layout: RelativeLayout) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(layout)

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val cont = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        .inflate(R.layout.my_item, parent, false) as RelativeLayout
    return ViewHolder(cont)
}


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return dataset.size
 }
}
```

Comment: add custom views to your xml layout and then populate it with your data set, adapter is responsible to convert your data set into the view

Comment: If `CarouselView` is the `ViewGroup` with the problem, then that is saying that you need to extend `CarouselView`, not plain old `ViewGroup`. If you then add a two-parameter constructor to it that takes a `Context` and an `AttributeSet` – `public MyViewGroup(Context c, AttributeSet a) { super(c, a); }` – you can just put it in your item layout, in place of the `CarouselView` – e.g.,  `<your.package.name.MyViewGroup>`.

Comment: may be [this](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView/issues/382) will help you!